# SQL Query related to joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

```
Select * 
into relatesupply 
from
    OrderByStore m 
m.Product_Name,m.Quantity,n.Quantity 
inner join 
    presentsupply n on m.Product_Name = n.Product_Name
```

I want `relatesupply` as a new table and join output will store at `relatesupply` ? How should I fire the query? Where `OrderByStore` and `presentsupply` are two tables

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: I am using SQl Server 2008

Comment: it shows an error    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'm'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query will create a table `relatesupply` as you need with inner join `OrderByStore`  and `presentsupply` :

```
SELECT        
    OrderByStore.Product_Name, OrderByStore.Quantity, 
    presentsupply.Product_Name AS Expr1, presentsupply.Quantity AS Expr2
INTO
    relatesupply
FROM            
    OrderByStore 
INNER JOIN
    presentsupply ON OrderByStore.Product_Name = presentsupply.Product_Name
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create the table in advance (either manually or in script) and then insert the data using the insert statement. Avoid using the * to select columns, name them. Just a much neater way to do things in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Relatesupply 
    select * 
    from OrderByStore m 
    join Presentsupply n on (Select * into  relatesupply  
                             from OrderByStore m  
                                  m.Product_Name,m.Quantity,n.Quantity  
                             inner join presentsupply n on m.Product_Name = n.Product_Name);
```

This query should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * 
into Relatesupply
from 
(
  select m.Product_Name,m.Quantity,n.Quantity 
  from OrderByStore m 
  inner join presentsupply n on m.Product_Name = n.Product_Name
) as X
```

Comment: Ops, previous answer for Oracle only. I'm try to correct.